# Insert update delete trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Dear all I´m having trouble with my trigger.

Am I doing this at all right, right now it only works for Insert. I think I´m pretty close tho please help me if you have the time.  I´m trying to store all the inserts, updates and deletes into the table customers_changelog via trigger. There is something wrong with the code I cant delete or update customers I can only insert new ones. Please help my I have been spending plenty of hours on this and just cant get this to work! :)

```
create table customers (
customerid int identity primary key,
name varchar(100) not null,
address varchar(100)
)
go

create table customers_changelog (
customerid int,
name varchar(100) not null,
address varchar(100),
change_user varchar(32),
change_time datetime,
change_action char(1) default 'I',
check (change_action = 'I' or change_action = 'D')
)
go


CREATE TRIGGER log_changes
ON customers
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--
-- Check if this is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE Action.
-- 
DECLARE @customerid1 as int;
DEClARE @name1 as varchar(32);
DECLARE @address1 as varchar(100);
DECLARE @change_action1 as char(1);
DECLARE @change_time1 as datetime;
DECLARE @change_user1 as varchar(32);

select  @customerid1 = c.customerid, @name1 = c.name, @address1 = c.address
from customers c, inserted i
where c.customerid = i.customerid 

SET @change_time1 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SET @change_user1 = CURRENT_USER;
INSERT INTO customers_changelog(customerid,name,address,change_action,change_time,change_user)
    VALUES(@customerid1,@name1,@address1,'I',@change_time1,@change_user1)
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN    
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
            INSERT INTO customers_changelog VALUES(@customerid1,@name1,@address1,'U',@change_time1,@change_user1)
            ELSE 
            INSERT INTO customers_changelog VALUES(@customerid1,@name1,@address1,'D',@change_time1,@change_user1)

END
ELSE 
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN;
END
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MS-SQL from syntax - So couple issues here:
1. Need to specify column lists in the "update" and "delete" inserts because the column order in the table doesn't match your inserts.
2. Can't use "inserted" data for delete insert

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[log_changes] ON [dbo].[customers] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @customerid1 as int;
    DEClARE @name1 as varchar(32);
    DECLARE @address1 as varchar(100);
    DECLARE @change_action1 as char(1);
    DECLARE @change_time1 as datetime;
    DECLARE @change_user1 as varchar(32);

    select  @customerid1 = c.customerid, @name1 = c.name, @address1 = c.address
    from customers c, inserted i
    where c.customerid = i.customerid 

    SET @change_time1 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    SET @change_user1 = CURRENT_USER;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN    
                IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
                INSERT INTO customers_changelog(customerid,name,address,change_action,change_time,change_user) 
                    VALUES(@customerid1,@name1,@address1,'U',@change_time1,@change_user1)
                ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    select  @customerid1 = d.customerid, @name1 = d.name, @address1 = d.address
                        from deleted d
                    INSERT INTO customers_changelog(customerid,name,address,change_action,change_time,change_user) 
                        VALUES(@customerid1,@name1,@address1,'D',@change_time1,@change_user1)
                END

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN;
        INSERT INTO customers_changelog(customerid,name,address,change_action,change_time,change_user)
            VALUES(@customerid1,@name1,@address1,'I',@change_time1,@change_user1) 
    END
END
```

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me. See the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043106/how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update/26043654#26043654