# How to determine if insert or update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Whenever INSERT is happened in the CUSTOMER table,I need to call the "**StoredProcedure1**"and 
UPDATE is happend in the  CUSTOMER table,I need to call the "**StoredProcedure2**" in the Trigger.
**How to determine if insert or update in the trigger**  from SQL Server 2008.

Some one can please help me how to solve?

**Code:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Notifications ON CUSTOMER
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @recordId varchar(20);
set @recordId= new.Id;
    //if trigger is insert at the time I call to SP1
        EXEC StoredProcedure1 @recordId
    //if trigger is Upadeted at the time I call to SP2
        EXEC StoredProcedure2 @recordId
END
```

Comment: it is not recommended to have trigger call procedures that have to execute one row at a time. It's really hurt the performence. Why don't you move your SP logic into the trigger??

Comment: A couple of really major things here. First of all you should NEVER use a scalar variable in a trigger that is populated from the inserted or deleted values. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation and your triggers need to handle multiple rows operations. Secondly if you need different logic for an insert than an update create two triggers. One for each type of operation.

Comment: I need to send an email to customers

Comment: DO NOT send an email in a trigger. You will slow your system down to unbelievably low levels. In cases like this what you should do is use the trigger to populate a queue table so the dml statements can be fast. Then have another process pick up the rows in the extra table and process them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**Let SQL Server be SQL Server, and have it do the work for you!**

Create separate triggers for each change event (insert,update and/or delete).
Put the logic for each into the trigger that needs it.
No need to have to check for the event type.

And don't call a procedure unless it is quick, fast, and can't block others.

Comment: ok I never call to Stored Procure,Can I send an email to customers in Trigger?

Comment: sp_send_dbmail is the msft system procedure to call for that. You can open your self up to a mess of hurt when you try to use SQL Server to email for anything other than error messages to internal  users. I would queue up message requests into a table and schedule a job to periodically send out the emails.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this problem would be to have two triggers, one for the insert and one for the update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertNotifications ON CUSTOMER
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @recordId varchar(20);
set @recordId= new.Id;
    //if trigger is insert at the time I call to SP1
        EXEC StoredProcedure1 @recordId

END

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateNotifications ON CUSTOMER
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @recordId varchar(20);
set @recordId= new.Id;
    //if trigger is Upadeted at the time I call to SP2
        EXEC StoredProcedure2 @recordId
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for trigger for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. This works fine on Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008

```
if (Select Count(*) From inserted) > 0 and (Select Count(*) From deleted) = 0
begin
   print ('Insert...')
end

if (Select Count(*) From inserted) = 0 and (Select Count(*) From deleted) > 0
begin
   print ('Delete...')
end

if (Select Count(*) From inserted) > 0 and (Select Count(*) From deleted) > 0
begin
   print ('Update...')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On an INSERT, the virtual DELETED table will be empty.

Comment: Can please tell me how can I implement my scenario,In UPDATE section I need to get the all old values to compare with new values then finally I need to call the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger comp
before
insert or delete or update
on student
referencing old as o new as n
for each row
begin
  if deleting then
           insert into student_backup values
      (:o.studid,:o.studentname,:o.address,:o.contact_no,:o.branch,sysdate);
  end if;
  if inserting then
        insert into student_backup values
      (:n.studid,:n.studentname,:n.address,:n.contact_no,:n.branch,sysdate);
 end if;
  if updating then
       insert into student_backup values
      (:o.studid,:o.studentname,:o.address,:o.contact_no,:o.branch,sysdate);
  end if;
end comp;
```

Comment: That is Oracle syntax.  The OP asked about SQL Server.